# Live Data observe for object single property change

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

In Android project implemented Android Architecture component successfully as per developer guideline but the problem is we can observe full object change using LiveData

```
  mQueViewModel.getLiveQuestion().observe(this, new Observer<Question>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Question question) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChanged: ");
            setQuestionDetails();
        }
    });
```

Any single object property change fire `OnChanged` this cause to set all data again to UI So is there any way to implement property change like `onDescriptionChange`, `onImageChange` ...

Answer (score 1):

To do that you could use the ViewModel to break the data in smaller pieces. Something like this should work:

```
private LiveData<Question> questions;
private MediatorLiveData<String> description;

public MQueViewModel() {

    description = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    description.addSource(questions, new Observer<Question>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Question question) {
            if (question == null) return;
            if (!question.description.equals(description.getValue())) {
                description.setValue(question.description);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

and have than have your UI subscribe to `description`. Add similar MediatorLiveData to any other property change u need.

Comment: don't you think its very lengthy solution, think if I have 20 properties in class?

Comment: Yes I think it will be very lengthy. I wouldn't do it at all as it seems to me that's premature optimization. But if you really want to, that's the way!

Comment: Please suggest something like Realm provide getChangedFields() , isFieldChanged(String fieldName)

Answer (score 0):

may be its so late but you can have two option

---

1-   implementing Property “Aware” MutableLiveData as described [here](https://medium.com/@tylerwalker/property-aware-mutablelivedata-with-kotlin-4fb5830ae730)

2- whenever the property changed set the value to itself

```
 private  var _currentPacket = MutableLiveData<PacketEntity>()
 fun test() {
     _currentPacket.value!!.someproperty= somevalue 
     _currentPacket.value=_currentPacket.value 
  }
```